# How can I start using web3js version 1.x? NPM installs an old version

Tags: npm, solidity, web3js

In the web3 version 1.x docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html it says to install web 3 using

```
npm install web3
```

but this installs version 0.2x.00.

so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Install from the github repo using the 1.0 branch directly:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js.git\#1.0ES6
```

EDIT: Adding example install into a new project directory.

```
$ npm install git+https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js.git\#1.0ES6

> web3@1.0.0-beta.24 postinstall C:\cygwin\home\adamk\eth\web3-1.0\node_modules\web3
> lerna bootstrap

lerna info version 2.9.0
lerna info Bootstrapping 20 packages
lerna info lifecycle preinstall
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna info Symlinking packages and binaries
lerna info lifecycle postinstall
lerna info lifecycle prepublish
lerna info lifecycle prepare
lerna success Bootstrapped 20 packages
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\cygwin\home\adamk\eth\web3-1.0\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\cygwin\home\adamk\eth\web3-1.0\package.json'
npm WARN web3-1.0 No description
npm WARN web3-1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN web3-1.0 No README data
npm WARN web3-1.0 No license field.

+ web3@1.0.0-beta.24
added 1 package in 65.026s
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: 'lerna' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then install lerna. `npm install -g lerna`

Comment: after installing lerna and again running the command you've provided earlier this is what i get:
lerna info version 2.9.0
lerna info Bootstrapping 20 packages
lerna info lifecycle preinstall
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna ERR! execute callback with error
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: npm install
lerna ERR! gyp ERR! build error
lerna ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
lerna ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit

Comment: See my edit for example run. You're having an issue with your specific environment. Make sure you're running with admin privileges. Try running the install in an empty project directory (as shown above) to make sure nothing else in your project is conflicting with it. If you continue to have issues, run the install in verbose mode to see if you can get more info on the underlying cause.

Comment: Specify a specific version in the npm registry. For example, "npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.26" is what I am currently using and is fine. Remove previous installation of web3 to prevent the possibility of a conflict. Please adhere to Adam Kipnis's request to get a verbose log